# JWT multiple audiences per resource server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin, jwt

After spending a number of hours researching using JWT in Web API using OWIN I'm still rather confused on what the purpose of the Audience represents. Some pages are saying that the audience is the resource server on which the token will be validated. Others suggest that audience is the client that is accessing the resource server and frequently actually refer to this value as client_id and audience interchangeably.

According to the JWT spec it appears the Audience is intended to be the resource server (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#page-9). So I don't see a need to ever have more than one Audience per API application. But a number of implementations are adding multiple Audiences to a single Web API app and Microsoft's implementation of JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions allows for it as well.

In these implementations where they are using the audience and the client_id interchangeably (here is one example: https://auth0.com/docs/server-apis/webapi-owin) I feel this too closely couples your resource servers to your clients and is enforcing the client claim on your resource server. I feel like this is the job of the authentication server (hence the ability to add multiple audience claims to the token according to the JWT spec).

I feel like I'm missing something important here. My goal is to be able to develop multiple API's that can be used by multiple clients but having to dynamically manage the audience claims at both the resource server and auth server seems to go against the spirit of JWT. Yet many people have implemented it otherwise and even MS allows multiple audiences per resource server so I was hoping for some clarity here.

Answer (score 2):

The `audience` identifies the intended "consumer" of the token. Normally it is the application (API) that receives the token from a client app.

Services that expect a JWT need to inspect (and validate)  the `audience` to prevent someone from sending (a valid) token that was meant for someone else.

You can imagine a situation where **API-1** and **API-2** use both role based security for example, and a user obtains a claim **admin** for **API-1**. If **API-2** doesn't check `audience` there's a chance the user can send the token (with admin claim in it) and succeed (when it shouldn't).

Comment: So I get that the audience needs to be validated but is there any scenario in which you could think where there would ever need to be more than one audience per API? If the API is the audience why would any API ever need to be configured to validate multiple audiences? I just can't imagine a use-case for this.

Comment: no, I'd think it is the opposite. Your token will have multiple audiences. meaning it can be used in many APIs.

Comment: So any ideas on why Microsoft's JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions allows for multiple audiences for a single API [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.jwt.jwtbearerauthenticationoptions.allowedaudiences%28v=vs.113%29.aspx#P:Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt.JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions.AllowedAudiences)?

Comment: My guess is that the implementation assumes the separation of the authentication server from the resource server(s).  The audience is any API (resource server) where a token should be valid.  This allows a single Authorization server to secure multiple API's.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but:
A JWT token should only contain one audience. It is the job of the developers/architects to design logical applications (~audience).
Imagine you have two UIs:

- Admin UI
- Consumer UI

Where as the Admin UI consumes

- service1
- service2
- service3

And the Consumer UI consumes

- service3
- service4
- service5

When you log into the admin UI, you don't want to request 3 tokens with 3 different audiences. Same is true for the consumer UI. That's why you design two logical applications:

- admin
- consumer

Now you tell your service1 and service 2 to check the JWT audience for "admin".
Service4 and service5 will check for "consumer".
Service3 will be fine with tokens issued for either "admin" or "consumer".